# Nokia Counter on WP7

Tags: api, windows-phone-7

I downloaded Nokia Counters and I dont understand how do they get sms count and call durations if there is no API that could support this?

Do they have any extra APIs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely they have deeper access. After all, it is only for their devices which means that they can not only exit sandbox, but access their own proprietary API.

It is similar to Youtube app, Adobe Reader app and deep links to marketplace.

I would really want to get access to such API :/

Comment: I confirm, this app uses a component written in native code. This is only allowed for OEM, not for third-party developers.